# Linha vertical entre divs

Tags: html, css

É possível fazer uma linha Vertical entre DIVs? queria criar um separador para os dados. Abaixo um exemplo do código que estou utilizando:

```
<div style="float:left; max-width:200px;max-height:200px;" class="text-center">
     <b>Telefone</b><br />
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telefone)
</div>
<div style="float:left; max-width:200px;max-height:200px;margin-left:10px;" class="text-center">
     <b>Celular</b><br />
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Celular)
</div>
```

Quero uma linha vergical entre elas já tentei por na propriedade da div no Style o  border-left, mas nem rolou...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto também pode ser utilizado caso queira colocar como um elemento separado:

```html
<hr width="1" size="100">
```

Você pode modificar o size para ficar do tamanho desejado.

Funciona também:

```html
<hr style=" transform: rotate(90deg); width: 100px; ">
```

Você pode claro colocar apenas a tag `<hr>`que é uma linha horizontal e virar 90º no CSS:

```css
hr {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Novamente pode alterar o width para ficar do tamanho desejado também.

Comment: obrigado :) funcionou aqui

Answer (score 3):

Ao que parece sua dúvida está mais voltada ao *CSS* (Estilo) do que as linguagens definidas nas `tags`. Veja, para por uma linha vertical entre as `divs` basta você por, como mencionou, um `border-left` no elemento mais à direita que já resolveria o problema.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
<div style="float:left; max-width:200px;max-height:200px;" class="text-center">
     <b>Telefone</b><br />
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telefone)
</div>
<div style="float:left; max-width:200px;max-height:200px;margin-left:10px; border-left:1px solid #666" class="text-center">
     <b>Celular</b><br />
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Celular)
</div>
```

Veja que foi adicionado dentro da propriedade style da segunda `div` o seguinte estilo: `border-left:1px solid #666`.

Uma outra abordagem seria usar o [Flexbox](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/flexbox/). Veja como ficaria nessa [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENKxzb).

abs.

Comment: Obrigado @CleitonPereira